# The callback does not call when multiprocessing

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I take a whole day to debug the code below. It is about multiprocessing. Please take a look.

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp


def printHello(x):
    print "ENTERING: printHello"
    time.sleep(2)
    print "QUITTING: printHello"
    return 'hello '+x

def log_result(result):
    print "ENTERING: log_result"
    time.sleep(2)
    print "QUITTING: log_result"

def main_multi():
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for i  in range(3):
        pool.apply_async(printHello, args=(i, ), callback=log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__=='__main__':
    print "ENTERING __main__"
    main_multi()
    print "QUITTING __main__"
```

I thought I would get
 "QUITTING: printHello", "ENTERING: log_result" and "QUITTING: printHello" among the output lines. What appears strange to me is that, printHello has not yet finished when the main program stops (no 'hello' printed out); the 'pool.join' statement seems be to ignored in some way.  Maybe the 'callback' or 'apply_async' above do not work as I expected. Any idea?

The output from my console is:

```
ENTERING __main__
ENTERING: printHello
ENTERING: printHello
ENTERING: printHello
QUITTING __main__
```

[EDIT] Interestingly, if I remove the 'time.sleep(2)' part, I get

```
ENTERING __main__
ENTERING: printHello
QUITTING: printHello
ENTERING: printHello
QUITTING: printHello
ENTERING: printHello
QUITTING: printHello
QUITTING __main__
```

But this still does not solve all the problems. Because 'hello' in 'helloPrint' is not printed out, whereas I do have a pool.join after apply_async.

[Edit2] I just add the 'import time'. The symptom persists: pool.join should  block until the process terminates, but that is not the case here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does removing the `time.sleep(2)` statements do anything?

Comment: Thanks for this hint. See my edits above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't imported the `time` module, so your calls to `time.sleep` cause the worker processes to error out. This is why you don't get the `"QUITTING"` messages, nor does the callback get called.

If you fix that issue, you'll still be getting errors in the workers when you try to produce the return value. You're adding the integer `x` you get passed to the string `"hello"`, which is not well defined. You need to convert the integer to a string for the string concatenation to work.

Comment: Wow! That is sharp! Do you know whether there a way to get such error information at runtime ?

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Now, though, I'm wondering how can one see errors generated by a worker process?

Comment: If you keep the `AsyncResult` value returned by the pool's `apply_async` method, you'll be able to get the exception by calling its `get` method (which raises the exception caught in the worker process). Python 3's `concurrent.futures` module does this a bit better, as the callbacks you can set up for asynchronous calls are called with the `Future` object itself in both normal and error situations.

Comment: I had a similar issue to this recently (with datetime rather than time), and I found that it helped to define `error_callback` as well as `callback` so that errors from each process are actually handled rather than the processes failing silently.